# JavaScript - Get and display current time in <input type="time"> while also working with <input type="date">

Tags: javascript, html

How do I display the current time in an input `<input type="time">` and hide its picker icon while working with another input `<input type="date">` and not affect it using JavaScript?

Thank you all.

Comment: You want to hide the time's picker or date's picker?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="time" class="time">
    <input type="date" class="date">
    <script>
        var date = new Date();

        // This will set the current date and time in both the inputs 
        var currentDate = date.toISOString().substring(0 , 10);

        var currentTime = date.toISOString().substring(11 , 16);

        document.querySelector('.date').value = currentDate;

        document.querySelector('.time').value = currentTime;
    </script>

    <style>
        /* Hide the time picker */
        input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
            display: none;
        }

        /* Hide the date picker icon */
        input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
            display: none
        }

    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can we get the time depending on the timezone?

Comment: You can set the timezone i guess in the date object